# How would i do this? I am trying to make an image in javascript be a button

Tags: javascript, image

```
   function create_button() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src ="img/Play.png";
    img.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("aye");
    });
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild;
}
```

Wanting to know how i can do this. I am trying to make an image in javascript be a button. Is there a better way than how i am doing it?

Comment: Your code is not correct. `myImg` is undefined. I think you intended `t` but the value of `t` is not the img-element. After fixing that, the code works right? What _better way_ are you looking for? There are other ways to insert nodes but they're really involved (such as using a document fragment notation).

Comment: If you want to get that effect, I'd personally just make my img look like a button and give it button behaviour (drop shadow which is removed while clicked)

Comment: I replaced "t" with "myImg" and it still didnt work.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks I just want an image to act as a button. Click it and it does something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function button1 () {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");      
    var myimg = document.getElementById("myImg").src = "Play.png";
    alert(myimg); // "Play.png", myimg is a string, not a DOM element
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    btn.appendChild(myImg);                                
    document.body.appendChild(btn);                  
}
```

This stuff isn't rocket science right? Just write it simply and step by step:

```
function create_button() {
    var button = document.createElement("button");      
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "Play.png";
    button.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

This will make the image clickable:

```
function create_button() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("hi");
    });
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

You can also style the button to make it look like it's not there:

```
button.nochrome {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fnno6r3g/

Comment: I'm fairly new to javascript. I've tried w3schools and other sites but i didn't understand it too well. But the code worked but it still has that button outline around it. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: Of course, you can have the image behave like a button.

Comment: How would i do that? Jonathon showed me a way but i need it inside a function.

Comment: I can also position it in the css right? Cause right now its outside of where i want it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It's at the bottom left of my screen outside of a canvas. My main page is inside a canvas. Apologies for not mentioning there was a canvas.

Comment: Then instead of `document.body.appendChild` do `document.getElementById("the_canvas").appendChild`.

Comment: Ive updated my code at the top for you to see. But it removed the button completely.

Comment: `document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(img);`.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) It is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach an event listener to your img with javascript:

```html
<img src="http://ingridwu.dmmdmcfatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/placeholder.png" height="200px"/>
<script>
    document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("do something");
    });
</script>
```

Then it will act as a "button" - it does something when you click it